# gopls extract function not working in neovim lsp

Tags: go, lua, neovim, language-server-protocol, gopls

I am using Neovim v0.8.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.
I have configured neovim LSP using mason plugin to use the Go language server gopls v0.13.1.

I can confirm that the language server works for some functions. For example with my LSP config (see below), I can rename a variable in a Go file.

Also when I print the capabilities of the language server using the nvim ex command `:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf_get_clients()[1].server_capabilities))`, I get the following included in the output:

```
  callHierarchyProvider = true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  codeActionProvider = {
    codeActionKinds = { "quickfix", "refactor.extract", "refactor.rewrite", "source.fixAll", "source.organizeImports" }
  },
  codeLensProvider = vim.empty_dict(),
  completionProvider = {
    triggerCharacters = { "." }
  },
```

However, I cannot get any of the other refactor code actions to work. I would like to select a range and then extract a function or similar.

In my LSP config, I have the following mappings:

```
map('n', '<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action)
map('v', '<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.range_code_action)
map('n', '<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename)
```

My leader is space, so if I select a range and then press `<space>ca`, I get the message:

```
No code actions available
```